# Proper way to handle nullable values in parameterized queries?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Suppose I'm querying a table, and null might be one of the values to look for.  A query that's set up like this

```cs
command.CommandText = "select * from People where Saluation = @salutation";

if(salutation != null) command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salutation", salutation);
else command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salutation", DBNull.Value);
```

won't return any results when salutation is null.  So I'm inclined to do this instead, but it feels ugly to me:

```cs
string whereClause;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(salutation))
{
    whereClause = "Salutation = @salutation";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salutation", salutation);
}
else whereClause = "Salutation is null";

command.CommandText = "select * from People where " + whereClause;
```

Is there a more correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably avoid concatenation to build your where clause.  You could change you sql to the following. May open your self up for SQL Injections attacks.

```
command.CommandText = "select * from People where (@salutation is null and salutation is null) or Saluation = @salutation";
```

Comment: Concatenation won't create an injection vulnerability if foreign strings are not being concatenated.

Comment: Very true, it's easier to slip into bad habits.

Comment: The original version returns all rows when @salutation is null - it should be (@salutation is null and salutation is null).  I just posted an edit, and will accept once it gets through peer review.

Answer (score 1):

You could add in an extra parameter that will specify whether you want to return null values or not, and modify your query slightly.

To use your example:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from People where ((@IsNull_Salutation = 1 AND Salutation IS NULL) OR (Saluation = @Salutation))"; 

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Salutation", salutation ?? (object)DBNull.Value); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("IsNull_Salutation", (salutation == null) ? 1 : 0);
```

This lets you keep your query fully parameterized. If you ever decide that you want to stop returning null values, you just have to change the value you pass in to the IsNull_Salutation parameter.

From memory, this is similar to how the SqlCommandBuilder class deals with null values in its auto-generated insert/update/delete queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function, setting a default value as second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:
Just use such a WHERE clause

```
WHERE @field IS NULL OR field = @field
```

Sql Server is smart enough to use the proper condition based on the value of @field parameter.
The important thing in this scenario - not to change the parameter value in the query before it will be used in SELECT stmt.

Answer (score -1):

```
command.CommandText = "select * from People where Saluation ";
command.CommandText += salutation != null ? ("= " + salutation) : "is NULL";
```

Comment: I'll just pass in my favorite salutation: `1; drop table people;`  :)

Comment: -1 for not using parameterized query and allowing Joviee to destroy the Soylent Green.